# Is there a simple HTTP API for Dialogflow v2?

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

I'm learning Dialogflow right now, and I'd like to connect a bot to some frontend web code. I know about the Node.js API for Dialogflow, but for my current purposes, it seems a little over-complicated. The only functionality I need right now is sending user input to the bot and receiving the bot's response, so it seems like setting up an entire server just to communicate with the bot is pretty excessive.

Is there a way to communicate with the bot from the frontend directly, like an HTTP API? Or is the NPM package the only option?

Answer (score 1):

This is the only endpoint that you need: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.sessions/detectIntent. As long as you get the authentication right you should be good to go.